# How to disable thumbnails for a folder in Linux?

Tags: linux, thumbnails

Is there some way to disable thumbnails in all file managers only for one folder and all subfolders?

I'm searching for the way that will works in all Linuxes or at last on Ubuntu, Fedora and CentOS.

Comment: Have you tried to do a round of Google search?

Comment: Sure. But, I don't found answer to my question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It has been answered on the Linux site's already: https://askubuntu.com/q/557643/117753